# Random image Array (xcode 6, swift2)

Tags: swift, xcode6

I do not know how to make array for random images. I want to know how to make a random image array and please help me by writing some code. I have done with the switch case but I did not want that I want random image so anyone help.

Comment: What have you tried so far in your attempt to solve the problem?  Could you post some code that you've tried?

Comment: Any update on my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is very clear but If you are asking how to create an Array of images using swift :

```
var arrayOfImages = ["image1.png","image2.png","image3.jpeg","image4.jpeg"]
```

But if you are trying to display an image each time the user click on a Button

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageView:UIImageView!

    @IBAction func ButtonWasTapped(sender:UIButton){

      var random = arc4random_uniform(5)
        switch(random){

        case 0: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image1.png")
        break

        case 1: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image2.jpg")
            break
        case 2: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image3.png")
            break
        case 3: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image4.jpg")
            break
        case 4: imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image5.jpg")
            break
        default:
            break;

        }

    }
```

Comment: how about font style? can we make an array of that font also ?Lamar

Comment: I don't really understand  what you want to do now

Comment: haha i was just asking that can we make an array of font styles and when again person taps on button so the label will come with different font styles @Lamar

Comment: Certainly you just need to create all the front then follow the same pattern

Comment: hey i have two IBOUTLET one is for author and for content so if i want random quote to generate but how to make sure that the author label is same to the content labe @Lamar

Answer (score 1):

You can use new GameplayKit and `GKRandomSource` in iOS9

```
import GameplayKit

var arrayOfImages = ["image1.png","image2.png","image3.jpeg","image4.jpeg"]

let randomOfImages = GKRandomSource().arrayByShufflingObjectsInArray(arrayOfImages)
```

Example from playground:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### Simple way to fetch random image from an image array

```
var imageArray = ["card1.png","card2.png","card3.png","card4.png","card5.png","card6.png")]
let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(6))
imgVw1.image = imageArray[random]
```